# Fusion Chart in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, fusioncharts

I am using fusion chart in my asp.net application. I want to use multiple fusion charts in a single page. But only one fusion chart is displayed.. Pls help me if any body knws about this problemm...

Iam using an ashx file(handler) for creating xml.

Advance thanks

Comment: pls refer this   http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/1311-multiple-charts-on-same-page-in-aspnet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used recently Fusion Charts and there is no lo limitation for that. 
You are able to use as much charts you want on a single page.
The problem certainly isn't fusion charts.

I invite you also to see an API that I've share in CodePlex. Turn much easier to display charts in your app.

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/

Total free, open source.

Here an example where I've used two chart on the same control and page without any problem
[image]

You could also send some part of your code for a better analyse.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use multiple charts in the same page using FusionCharts, please specify unique chartId for each chart.